# Creation of table with images CodeIgniter

Tags: php, html, codeigniter

The table displays only text, where images column should display actual image instead of just the name of image.

Everything else is fine and works perfectly but how to display the pictures?

controller code:

```
function getData() 
    {
        //check if the user is already logged in
        if($this->session->userdata('logged_in'))
        {
        //the user is already logged in -> display the secret content
        redirect('logged');
             //get the session data
        $session_data = $this->session->userdata('logged_in');

        //get the username from the session and put it in $data
        $data['user'] = $session_data['username'];

        $config['base_url'] = site_url('LittleController/getData/');
        $config['total_rows'] = $this->littlemodel->record_count('products');
        $config['per_page'] = 10;
        $this->pagination->initialize($config);
        $data['Products'] = $this->littlemodel->getData(10, $this->uri->segment(3));

        foreach ($data['Products'] as &$row)
        {
        $img = $row['image'];
        $row['image']= "<img src='resources/images/thumbs/.$img'>";
        //img('resources/images/thumbs/'.$img);

        }
        //$data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
            $this->load->view('mainpage1', $data);
        }
        else
        {
            //user isn't logged in -> display login form
            $data['user'] = "Guest";
            $config['base_url'] = site_url('LittleController/getData/');
            $config['total_rows'] = $this->littlemodel->record_count('products');
            $config['per_page'] = 10;
            $this->pagination->initialize($config);
            $data['Products'] = $this->littlemodel->getData(10, $this->uri->segment(3));
            $data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
            $this->load->view('mainpage1', $data);

        }
    }
```

model code:

```
        public function getData($limit, $offset) 
    {
        $this->db->limit($limit, $offset);
        $this->db->select('productName');
        $this->db->select('productLine');
        $this->db->select('productScale');
        $this->db->select('productDescription');
        $this->db->select('buyPrice');
        $this->db->select('image');
        $resultset = $this->db->get('products');
        return $resultset->result_array();
    }
```

view code:

```
    $tmpl = array ( 'table_open'  => '<table z-index="1000" id="table">' );
    $this->table->set_caption("List of Products");
    $this->table->set_heading('Name','Product Line','Product Scale','Product Description','Price per unit(€)','Image');
    $this->table->set_template($tmpl);
    echo $this->table->generate($Products);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the controller I have to change

```
$row['image']= "<img src='resources/images/thumbs/.$img'>";
```

to

```
$row['image']= img(array('src'=>'resources/images/thumbs/'.$img.'', 'alt'=>'','width'=>'100px', 'height'=>'100px'));
```

that's sets the issue.

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to find which section is executed user login section.

If login section is not loaded, there is no option to display the image the product array.

so please ensure it

If login section is loaded, it can not find the product array() because before it redirects ('logged') so please correct it and works for you